# 403 Forbidden on site with urllib3

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-403

So I am working on a project crawling different sites. All sites work except for `caesarscasino.com`.
No matter what I try I get a 403 Forbidden Error. I have searched on here and others to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib3
import urllib.request, urllib.error
from urllib.request import Request
import ssl

try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib.request import urlopen

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context #  overrides the default function for context creation with the function to create an unverified context.
urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
url = 'https://www.caesarscasino.com/'
req = Request(url, headers=headers) #opens the URL 
result = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

print(result)
```

With this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sp\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 30, in <module>
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\sp\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Forbidden
```

Comment: In a browser I find that I can't reach it with `https` but only `http`

Comment: @AndrewAllaire That got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with scraping the web is, that not a lot of people like being scraped. Thus they do not allow a machine (which you scraper is) to access that page. This is the error you are getting. It basically means, do not access that site, when you are a programm. However, there are ways around that. Like spoofing the IP address and rotating headers, while your programm checks out this site. I already answered that question on how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785877/spoofing-ip-address-when-web-scraping-python/56654164#56654164). Check it out and let me know in the comments whether or not that works for you.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code in that solution. Why do I need this loop? 
``` 
for n in range(1, 20):
    req = Request('http://icanhazip.com')
```
Is that request where I'd do mine?

Comment: Also my main goal is to just get the sites status code

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issues are related to the fact that it's `https`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485772/correct-way-to-make-a-python-https-request-using-requests-module) for info on how to fix that.

Comment: I appreciate the help but see above comments that was not the issue